# Change code in gradle dependency in runtime

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have gradle dependency from maven central. I need in same changes in this library. I can manually open `jar` library, decompile, edit, compile (create fake-android project for create `.class` file, release in it in `jar`), add to project `libs` and remove it from gradle's dependency, but it's not user-friendly. Is it possible make changes more easy?

In library I have class

```
public class BaseWebView extends WebView {
...
}
```

there I need add

```
@Override
public void loadData(String data, String mimeType, String encoding) {
//do same thing with string date
super.loadData(data, mimeType, encoding);
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to provide your **dynamic code block** (logic) that changes runtime from app module to library if possible.

Comment: @JeelVankhede done. Do you need in any other information?

Comment: One question that I might misunderstood, do you have just jar file or you're already having source code that you can modify?

Comment: I have complied `jar`file, that I what modify.

Comment: Another solution is to use that jar library in your project, Now extend that library `BaseWebView` class in your project *(I.e. class `ProjectWebView extends BaseWebView`)*. Now override your required method `loadData` in your class and write logic. don't call super if you don't want base method logic. Now use your `ProjectWebView` class in your project rather than `BaseWebView` class.

Comment: I have other classes in lib that use `BaseWebView` in extends. in this way I need override all classes that use `BaseWebView`. and all classes where calls classes that extends `BaseWebView`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202346/discussion-between-nikolay-and-jeel-vankhede).